# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" gets ignored

Tags: android, webview

My View contains only a WebView which is set to maximum width and height, and I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `activity_main.xml`, but it didn't work. I also tried with `adjustPan`, but that got ignored too. My WebView contains a site with a text box at the bottom, and when I activate the text box, the on-screen keyboard should appear and the screen should resize/get pushed up so that the text box will still be visible. Instead, the keyboard appears over the content and obscures the text box, not allowing the user to see what they type.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/nebView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to add them to Manifest file > activity section : `<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it either programatically in the activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

or right in the manifest

```
<application ... >
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
    ...
</activity>
...
```

You can find further informations here --> https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility

Comment: Thank you! The code solution actually worked, but the manifest method did not.